# Using reflection to find all linq2sql tables and ensure they match the database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, generics, reflection

I'm trying to use reflection to automatically test that all my linq2sql entities match the test database.  I thought I'd do this by getting all the classes that inherit from DataContext from my assembly:

```
var contexttypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (BaseRepository<,>)).GetTypes().Where(
       t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DataContext)));
foreach (var contexttype in contexttypes)
{
    var context = Activator.CreateInstance(contexttype);
    var tableProperties = type.GetProperties().Where(t=> t.PropertyType.Name == typeof(ITable<>).Name);
    foreach (var propertyInfo in tableProperties)
        {
            var table = (propertyInfo.GetValue(context, null));
        }
}
```

So far so good, this loops through each `ITable<>` in each datacontext in the project.  If I debug the code, "table" is properly instantiated, and if I expand the results view in the debugger I can see actual data.

BUT, I can't figure out how to get my code to actually query that table.  I'd really like to just be able to do table.FirstOrDefault() to get the top row out of each table and make sure the SQL fetch doesn't fail.  But I cant cast that table to be anything I can query.

Any suggestions on how I can make this queryable?  Just the ability to call .Count() would be enough for me to ensure the entities don't have anything that doesn't match the table columns.

Comment: By "Match", are you referring to matching the data types? Or are you also looking at the structure (foreign keys, etc.) and the data itself?

Comment: We've had issues where someone would drop a column from a table but forget to remove it from the dbmls, causing exceptions whenever that datacontext tried to access the table.  I'm really just trying to catch those in one place, so my repository unit tests don't actually have to hit the real database later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the table object you can cast it into the non-generic `ITable` interface and then use the `OfType<object>()` extension method to get an `IEnumerable<object>` which you can query:

```
object tableObject = GetTableFromReflection();
ITable table = (ITable)tableObject;
table.OfType<object>().FirstOrDefault();
```

EDIT: Just saw this SO ad on this page. See its second bullet:

[image]

Now that's what I call targeted advertising!

Comment: Aha, the table.OfType<object> was the secret sauce I was missing.  Thank you very much!